# How to set the color of items in a listbox

Tags: python, tkinter

I am making a `Listbox` which should contain lines from two lists.

Here is my rough draft:

```
LISTBOX = Listbox(master)

for line in LIST1:
    for lin in LIST2:
        LISTBOX.insert(END, line)
        LISTBOX.insert(END, lin)
```

Now, I want the lines from `LIST1` to be marked (highlighted in blue) automatically in the listbox.
Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
LISTBOX.insert(END, line)
LISTBOX.itemconfigure(END, background="blue")
```

Comment: It doesn't work for me, I get _tkinter.TclError: bad listbox index "-background": must be active, anchor, end, @x,y, or a number

Comment: @zvisofer: you are correct. My mistake, and I apologize. I was thinking that the `insert` method returned the index of the new item, but it does not. You need to use any valid index as the first element. I updated my answer.